# Drawing 100 circles with IDs and associating mouse events with them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js, kineticjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple task (SVG vs. Canvas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464788/simple-task-svg-vs-canvas)

I am trying to draw/paint a number of circles and want to identify them with IDs on mouse over or mouse click. 
I was trying to do this using KineticJS, not able to achieve as I am beginner at javascript.

Apart from that I just want to capture the normal mouse events (left/right click) and won't be moving or playing with these circles apart from mouse events. So is the KineticJS is the right lib. to use ? How about  Raphael JS/d3 etc. {By any chance can this is easily achieved by just Jquery/Dojo)
Only important thing is to draw large number of circles, ability to identify them uniquely and associate mouse events with them.

PS: Yes I Also want to accomplish the ability to zoom in/out the space/canvas in which these circles are drawn.

Please suggest. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code, You can find the circle ID by mousemove on the circle

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      canvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 578,
          height: 200
        });
        var circlesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var tooltipLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'purple'];
        var colorIndex = 0;

        var circleId ;

        for(var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {( function() {
            var i = n;
            var color = colors[colorIndex++];
            if(colorIndex >= colors.length) {
              colorIndex = 0;
            }
            circleId = "CircleID_" + i;
            var randX = Math.random() * stage.getWidth();
            var randY = Math.random() * stage.getHeight();
            var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
              x: randX,
              y: randY,
              radius: 10,
              fill: color,draggable:true,
              id:circleId
            });

            circle.on('mousemove', function() {
              // update tooltip
              var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
              tooltip.setPosition(mousePos.x + 5, mousePos.y + 5);
              tooltip.setText('ID: ' + stage.get("#CircleID_" + i)[0].attrs.id);
              tooltip.show();
              tooltipLayer.draw();
            });

            circle.on('mouseout', function() {
              tooltip.hide();
              tooltipLayer.draw();
            });

            circlesLayer.add(circle);
          }());
        }
        var tooltip = new Kinetic.Text({
          text: '',
          fontFamily: 'Calibri',
          fontSize: 12,
          padding: 5,
          visible: false,
          fill: 'black',
          opacity: 0.75,
          textFill: 'white'
        });

        tooltipLayer.add(tooltip);
        stage.add(circlesLayer);
        stage.add(tooltipLayer);
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NkzF2/