# Simple task (SVG vs. Canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js, kineticjs

I just want to make 200 clickable nodes (capture mouse events) which are connected by lines. 
Each node has some data associated with them in form of live data streams ( for simplicity assume CSVs) and clicking on node shows up the values plotted in a graph.

- The area in which all these nodes and lines are there, should be zoom-able.

Even after googling a lot, I confused for something as simple as this SVG is more suited or Canvas. 
Moreover what libraries will be best for the purpose. Like for Canvas we have KineticJS (with HTML5) and for SVGs we have d3 and all.

Experts, Please suggest. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is way better for that.
Canvas has no mouse events, you would have use a picking technic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But using KinectJs , I was easily able to associate mouse events, which added to the confusion.

Comment: they is is a question of how much effect and intense drawing. SVG is "dom" it is realyl easy to play with but for anything intense it is nowhere near the performances of the canvas. But SVG is quite performant. I'd ro SVG, for retina screens.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you have complex visuals associated with each node, it would work much faster if you rasterize a node once, then clone and draw on canvas rather than use SVG. It can be done using [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org) for example (and it has some support for mouse events). If your nodes are simple, say, simple rectangles or something, you can use SVG. Some browsers are more efficient with SVG than others. For example, IE9 has very efficient SVG support, so if you target particular browser, check out it's SVG drawing speed first.

BTW, Paper.js is particularly useful if you want to rotate, zoom, move objects and groups of objects etc. It has a pretty good support for that.

Comment: No No .. My nodes are just simple squares. On Clicking on these squares, respective plot start appearing in the upper left corner of screen. That is it.  So, essentially I just to associated mouse events. (left - right click ..mouseover with these nodes) + want t zoom in/out the whole thing on scrolling in the blank area.

Comment: Ok, there are 2 options then - SVG using a library like d3 you mentioned or Raphaël, or you can use Paper.js for almost the same functionality implemented for Canvas. It's easier to process mouse events for SVG, but you can do that in Paper.js as well. In case of simple nodes both options are similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladich. I also plan to make some contours later around the nodes.. will this functionality favor SVG/Canvas over other ? And have you ever used KineticJS .. Any views on that ?  .. And can this is done using Dojo ?? .. Sorry about asking too many questions in one

Comment: I never used KineticJS. It looks like it's pretty similar to Paper.js, just another vector library for Canvas, so it's probably useful for your task. It should be faster than SVG drawing in case of 200 nodes. If you want to make your nodes more complex later or to create more nodes, the difference in performance between Canvas and SVG will be more apparent.